# How to read a matrix saved in a .json file and covert it to an Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, matrix

I am wondering how to read a numeric matrix saved in a .json file and covert it to an Array type in java?

Basically, I did most of my coding in R, I want to save a matrix in some particular format. I am also open to save it into .csv or .txt file, I am wondering if there is an easy way of convert this file to an array in java. I do not mind if it is .csv, .txt or .json file. I just want some easy java codes to read it into an array since I am not fluent in java.  I want to get the number of rows and number of columns dynamically without pre-specify the array as

```
double[][] array = new double[4][5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the [jackson json library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) and then:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        double[][] array;
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.json")) {
            array = mapper.readValue(in, double[][].class);
        }

        // Do something with array...
    }
}
```